# Linking to an ID does not work

Tags: html, anchor

I have an image that, when clicked I'd like to take the user to the top of the page (it's a "back to top" link.)

I have linked the image using an ID to my 'navigation' div using the code below, as I have been told is the correct way to do so, but it does nothing.

[Live site](http://www.jamesperrett.co.uk/testsite)

**HTML**

```
<div id="navigation">
     stuff in here
</div>
```

and

```
<!-- Back to top link -->
  <div class="bottom">
    <a href="#navigation">
      <img src="images/back_top.png" />
    </a>
  </div>
```

This doesn't seem to do anything though, I thought the name attribute was deprecated and thus id's should be used instead but this doesn't do anything?

Comment: The `#navigation` link is always on screen (`position: fixed`) so there's no need to jump to it. Link to an element that will stay at the top.

Comment: What do you suggest then? That is the only thing that is at the top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your `#navigation` element is positioned with `position: fixed` it is always on screen. You need to link to an element that will stay at the top of the document.

You could add in another element, or add an `id` to the body. Alternatively, change the `position` of the navigation so it stays in flow. Or, you could use JavaScript to animate a scroll to the top (e.g. with jQuery `.animate` and the `scrollTop` property).

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense now. However, what can I link it to? The navigation is the only thing that is at the top of the page and I don't know if it's possible to link to the html tag?

Comment: @Francesca - I've added some suggestions to the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I thought about the body but the body is not at the top of the document so pretty pointless! I'll have a search for the scrolltotop function then. I am t a loss for what to do as you can't link to the html and there is nothing else higher that isn't fixed!

Comment: @Francesca - If you put an element (with content - that's important, it must have some content) before the nav bar, and link to that, it should work. The nav bar should hide the content of the new element, so it should never be visible. I gave it a quick try by modifying the DOM dynamically on your live example, and it seems ok at first glance.

Answer (score 1):

Put this:

```
<a name="top"> </a>
```

right after/before your `navigation` div.

Then, change

```
<a href="#navigation">
```

to

```
<a href="#top">
```

**P.S.:** After looking at page-source, I'd suggest you put it just after the `<body>` tag.

Comment: The body tag is not at the top of the page, so that would just link to the top of the body, not the top of the page....

Comment: @Francesca  Your page content is contained withing the body tag. So, this will work.

Comment: The body tag doesn't start at the top of the page, so it links you to the top of the body, which is several hundred pixels down the page.

Answer (score 1):

you have linked it to something which *stays already* on the screen(**Fixed positioned**). link it something which is not fixed positioned .

Comment: There isn't anything else on the page that isn't either fixed, or is at the top :(

Comment: can't you link it with `ribbontext`

Answer (score 0):

Just to throw this out there for people coming along reading this... Linking to an A NAME is deprecated and not a best practice... Linking to an ID is the best way to go in the long run.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html